# Sort an associative array by using another array's ordered key-value association

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

Finding the right title for this was next to impossible.

Imagine this scenario:

We have an array that contains certain product tags. The key is each tag's unique **id** and the value is its label:

**Available Tags**

```
Array (
  [3] => Sweet
  [4] => Sour
  [5] => Bitter
  [6] => Winter
  [7] => Organic
)
```

We have another array which contains the tags that have been selected. The selection has a specific order which is defined by the **key**, while the value represents the **id** (of the actual tag we see in array #1).

**Selected Tags in Specific Order**

```
Array (
  [10] => 4
  [20] => 3
  [30] => 7
)
```

**My theoretical Approach**

Certainly i could go about foreach-ing through the second array, collecting the appropriate values (that correspond to the first array's entries) in a new array. Then i could iterate over the first array and add all the values (to the new array) which are not yet present in the new array.

Quite honestly - that doesn't feel very professional. Unfortunately, i have no idea how to do this better.

**Question**

How can i neatly sort the first array (**Available Tags**) by using the chronology defined by the second array (**Selected Tags**)?

**Note**

I want to end up with all items from the first array. Not just the ones that are listed in the second one.

In case someone's curious: this is for multiple-selects which are sortable. Items which have been selected are sortable and must therefore appear in the right order. The other items order doesn't matter. My server-side data handler class gives me these two arrays as described, so that's what i got to work with.

Comment: It's not possible to sort all the elements of the first array based on the order in the second array, because the second array only references some of the elements of the first array. What do you want to do with the elements that aren't referenced in the second array?

Comment: Good point. Well, it is possible, of course. But still, you are right - what to do with the rest? Well it's unimportant to be honest. It is only of importance that the entries defined in the second array end up in the sorted array in the right order. The other entries can stay anywhere - before or after the ones mentioned in the second array, that is.

Comment: Does this data come from database?

Comment: Yes, effectively it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses `uksort()`. Elements of the `$tags` array that are not present in the `$order` array are sorted to the end, and the relative order between them is undefined.

```
function my_sort($a, $b) {
    global $order;

    if(in_array($a, $order)) {
        if(in_array($b, $order)) {
            // Both $a and $b have an order
            return array_search($a, $order) - array_search($b, $order);
        }
        else {
            // Only $a has an order, so it goes before $b
            return -1;
        }
    }
    else if(in_array($b, $order)) {
        // Only $b has an order, so it goes before $a
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        // Neither $a or $b has an order, so we don't care how they're sorted
        return 0;
    }
}

uksort($tags, 'my_sort');
```

Comment: If you change the sign of `-1` and `1` in the function, the "unordered" elements will go first in stead.

Comment: This works like a charm! Thank you! I preferred using it as an anonymous function i pass to `uksort()` thus being able to rid myself of the usage of `global`. Example: `uksort($tags, function($a,$b) use ($order) { ... });`

Comment: @SquareCat Even better :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just loop in your second array and build a new one using keys

```
$new = array();
foreach($array2 as $key => $val)
{
    $new_array[] = $array1[$val];
}
```

Now the selected items are ordered in your `$new_array`

[**Sample**](http://codepad.org/DRK5Jab3)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid iterating over the arrays and instead being able to use some of PHPs built in array handling functions (which i am, unfortunately, not very well taught in). Also, i should have clarified and will update my question accordingly: i intend to end up with ALL items from the first array. not just the ones in the second one.